# NetTrain with Quadro

Tags: neural-networks, gpu

I have an Nvidia Quadro P620/PCIe/SSE2 graphics card on my linux box (Ubuntu 18.04):

```
<<CUDALink`
CUDAQ[] (*True*)
CUDADriverVersion[] (* 390.116.0 *)
```

But using `TargetDevice->"GPU"` fails.

*What is the canonical way to fix this if possible or check that the device not supported?*

**Related:**

- https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1085633

Comment: Update drivers. For CUDA 10, the minimum version is 410.48 (https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html)